# Flutter BlocListener doesn't emit new states

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have the following Bloc:

```html
class ClockBloc extends Bloc<ClockEvent, ClockState> {
      const ClockBloc() : super(const ClockState()) {
        on<ClockEventAddClock>(_addClock);
      }
      
      Future<void> _addClock(
        ClockEventAddClock event,
        Emitter<ClockState> emit,
      ) async {
        List<String> newItems = /* Some logic */;
        bool error = /* Some logic */;
        emit(ClockState(items: newItems, isError: error));
      }
    }

    class ClockState extends Equatable {
      const ClockState(this.items = const <String>[], this.isError = false,);
      final List<String> items;
      final bool isError;
      
        @override
      List<Object?> get props => [isError];
    }
```

Now, in my widget, I have a BlocListener which is supposed to display a dialog box (on button press) if state.isError = true. The thing is, the bloc may return the exact same state consecutively(when you keep pressing the button) - meaning the listener won't be triggered, and the dialog is never shown again.

How can I listen to the same state and trigger a dialog as long as state.isError = true?

UI:

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<ClockBloc, ClockState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isError) {
          /*Display dialog*/
          // this will only show when isError goes from 'false' -> 'true',
          // and not from 'true' -> 'true''
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I understand that since I'm using **Equatable**, the new state I'm emitting is compared against the previous one, and since they're identical, the new state is never emitted. So what approach would you choose? I thought about changing to some default state right before I emit the data back, but I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: share the ui code with listener please too

Comment: I added a simplified version of my UI

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131594/1640425

Comment: alternatively, you could change BlocListener to BlocConcumer and set parameter buildWhen: true, that would cause rebuild on any state change. seems more straightforward to me. or design a better condition for buildWhen that would rebuild on every error state, but for other states only if they are not equal. I prefer this approach. if you're interested, I can share as an answer.

Comment: Sounds great, please share it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at most/all of the examples on [bloclibrary.dev](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted), you'll see that all state changes rely on an enum called status, and a `copyWith` method.

Your state class in that format would look like this.

```
enum ClockStatus { initial, loading, success, error } // or whatever makes sense for your case

/// This is just for convenience so you can use `state.status.isError`
extension ClockStatusX on ClockStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == ClockStatus.initial;
  bool get isLoading => this == ClockStatus.loading;
  bool get isSuccess => this == ClockStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == ClockStatus.error;
}

class ClockState extends Equatable {
  const ClockState({
    this.status = ClockStatus.initial,
    this.items = const <String>[],
  });

  final List<String> items;
  final ClockStatus status;

  ClockState copyWith({
    List<String>? items,
    ClockStatus? status,
  }) {
    return ClockState(
      items: items ?? this.items,
      status: status ?? this.status,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status, items];
}
```

So then your updated bloc would look like this.

```
class ClockBloc extends Bloc<ClockEvent, ClockState> {
  ClockBloc() : super(const ClockState()) {
    on<ClockEventAddClock>(_addClock);
  }

  Future<void> _addClock(
    ClockEventAddClock event,
    Emitter<ClockState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: ClockStatus.loading)); // this will always force a new state change, but in this case you don't have to react to it if you don't need to

    List<String> newItems = /* Some logic */;
    bool error = /* Some logic */;

    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        items: newItems,
        status: error ? ClockStatus.error : ClockStatus.success,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then your listener callback would look like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<ClockBloc, ClockState>(listener: (context, state) {
      if (state.status.isError) {
        /*Display dialog*/
        // since there is always an emit of ClockStatus.loading before ClockStatus.error, this will always show in an error state
      }
    });
  }
```

That will sort out your issue.

As a general suggestion, I recommend error handling with a try/catch approach

```
Future<void> _addClock(
    ClockEventAddClock event,
    Emitter<ClockState> emit,
  ) async {
    List<String> newItems = [];
    emit(state.copyWith(status: ClockStatus.loading));
    try {
      // init your list
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          items: newItems,
          status: ClockStatus.success,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: ClockStatus.error,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```